# Unity просит обновить компилятор?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor

Только сегодня установил новую версию Unity, и она уже просит обновить компилятор.

Как это сделать, при условии, что сторонние gradle (чтобы понизить версию, см. скриншоты) Unity не одобряет?
Переустановка движка не поможет.
2020 версия тоже имеет ошибки с gradle.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Новые ошибки:]

```
warning: C:\Unity\Go-Little-Rockstar-master\Go-Little-Rockstar-master\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\libs\classes.jar(com/samsung/android/gamesdk/GameSDKManager.class): major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
Note: C:\Unity\Go-Little-Rockstar-master\Go-Little-Rockstar-master\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Unity\Go-Little-Rockstar-master\Go-Little-Rockstar-master\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity\androidnotifications\UnityNotificationManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\gumir\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

0x00007ff77f86beed (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x00007ff77f872bc9 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00007ff7807e07d3 (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x00007ff780e7708d (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00007ff77e9d5fa2 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x00000252aac2686a (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x00000252aac266db (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
0x00000252aac25b5e (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
0x00000252aae29b0a (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
0x00000252aae28ec3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.GradleInvokationException:ParseAndShowException ()
0x00000252aac0cdbb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner:RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext)
0x00000252aaddb2eb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput)
0x00000252aad8546b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&)
0x00000252aad8418c (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,string,string,string,int,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
0x00000252aad847bf (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_int_int_object_object_object_int_int_int_object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ffcd33cfe24 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:3445] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffcd330e764 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3066] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffcd330e8fc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3113] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff77f7906a4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff77f78b224 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff7811e6361 (Unity) CallMono
0x00007ff7811ee4b7 (Unity) PostprocessPlayer
0x00007ff7811e914f (Unity) DoBuildPlayer_PostBuild
0x00007ff7811e71ee (Unity) DoBuildPlayer
0x00007ff7811db34d (Unity) BuildPlayer
0x00007ff77f07555d (Unity) BuildPipeline::BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
0x00007ff77efdd83f (Unity) BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
0x00000252aaa0c2a8 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck (string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,string[],bool)
0x00000252aaa0ad63 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
0x00000252aaa0098b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
0x00000252aa90b763 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
0x00000252aa8d67a3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings ()
0x00000252aa86e9d3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI ()
0x00000252aa67d799 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect)
0x00000252aa67d293 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect)
0x00000252aa65b073 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:OldOnGUI ()
0x00000252aa4eb3d1 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x00000252aa657263 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x00000252aa7ef61b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool)
0x00000252aa7ef303 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,bool)
0x00000252aa9cf83b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUIRaw (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x00000252aa9d8813 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x000002520d28224b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x000002520d233806 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtTargetPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x00000252aa9d1213 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy:DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x000002520d22d006 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ApplyDispatchingStrategies (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,bool)
0x000002520d22bb23 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x000002520d24086b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
0x000002520d23b63b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate ()
0x000002520d23b3bb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate:Dispose ()
0x000002520d22c473 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x000002520d22aaa3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x000002520d22a5eb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x00000252aa47439b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel)
0x00000252aa473563 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x00000252aa472f84 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
0x00000252aa472c7b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2 (int,intptr)
0x00000252aa472725 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x00000252aa472966 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_intptr_intptr& (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ffcd33cfe24 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:3445] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffcd330e764 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3066] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffcd330e8fc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3113] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff77f7906a4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff77f78b224 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff77f784b45 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<void>
0x00007ff77f88da9a (Unity) Scripting::UnityEngine::GUIUtilityProxy::ProcessEvent
0x00007ff7802c8fa6 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
0x00007ff780810eab (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent
0x00007ff7802c8dba (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEvent
0x00007ff780811dfb (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages
0x00007ff78080b9cc (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc
0x00007ffd2ec81c4c (USER32) CallWindowProcW
0x00007ffd2ec80ea6 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
0x00007ff7807e67f3 (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff7807eb21b (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff781b7053e (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007ffd2ef154e0 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007ffd2ff8485b (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

Это же лог ошибки сборки?

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 54 seconds (54440 ms)
0x00007ff77f86beed (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x00007ff77f872bc9 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00007ff7807e07d3 (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x00007ff780e7708d (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00007ff77e9d5fa2 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x00000252aac2686a (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x00000252aac266db (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
0x00000252aac25b5e (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
0x00000252aae29b0a (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
0x00000252aaa0b62b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
0x00000252aaa0098b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
0x00000252aa90b763 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
0x00000252aa8d67a3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings ()
0x00000252aa86e9d3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI ()
0x00000252aa67d799 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect)
0x00000252aa67d293 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect)
0x00000252aa65b073 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:OldOnGUI ()
0x00000252aa4eb3d1 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x00000252aa657263 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x00000252aa7ef61b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool)
0x00000252aa7ef303 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,bool)
0x00000252aa9cf83b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUIRaw (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x00000252aa9d8813 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x000002520d28224b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x000002520d233806 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtTargetPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x00000252aa9d1213 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy:DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x000002520d22d006 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ApplyDispatchingStrategies (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,bool)
0x000002520d22bb23 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x000002520d24086b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
0x000002520d23b63b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate ()
0x000002520d23b3bb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate:Dispose ()
0x000002520d22c473 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x000002520d22aaa3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x000002520d22a5eb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x00000252aa47439b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel)
0x00000252aa473563 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x00000252aa472f84 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
0x00000252aa472c7b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2 (int,intptr)
0x00000252aa472725 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x00000252aa472966 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_intptr_intptr& (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ffcd33cfe24 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:3445] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffcd330e764 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3066] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffcd330e8fc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3113] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff77f7906a4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff77f78b224 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff77f784b45 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<void>
0x00007ff77f88da9a (Unity) Scripting::UnityEngine::GUIUtilityProxy::ProcessEvent
0x00007ff7802c8fa6 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
0x00007ff780810eab (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent
0x00007ff7802c8dba (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEvent
0x00007ff780811dfb (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages
0x00007ff78080b9cc (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc
0x00007ffd2ec81c4c (USER32) CallWindowProcW
0x00007ffd2ec80ea6 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
0x00007ff7807e67f3 (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff7807eb21b (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff781b7053e (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007ffd2ef154e0 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007ffd2ff8485b (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

Comment: Это предупреждение, я не уверен что именно это ошибка сборки, предоставьте весь лог ошибки сборки

Comment: Во-первых, спасибо за помощь. Во-вторых, вставил в конец вопроса.

Comment: Может будет полезно, мне помогло удаление папки из проекта .gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, всё оказалось проще, чем я думал (на самом деле, я мучился с этим месяц, боже).

Найдите папку C:\Users\имя пользователя\ .android и удалите файлы debug.keystore и debug.keystore.lock. Движок сам восстановит эти файлы, когда начнётся компиляция. Но восстановит правильно.

Comment: Очевидный выход из ситуации) Я просто не такой частый пользователь Дебаг хранилище, использую только собственные, поэтому не подумал о таком варианте

Answer (score 1):

Ошибки в логах указываются после `FAILURE: "Тип_ошибки"`, и далее. Тут стоит присмотреться и увидеть `Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\gumir\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format` и с прямого перевода можно понять, что проблема с хранилищем ключей, что-то произошло с дебаг хранилищем, попробуйте создать своё хранилище, использовать его и собрать сборку заного

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\gumir\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format
```

Comment: Я видел это сообщение, но не знал, что с ним делать. :( Но всё равно спасибо за отзывчивость. <3

Comment: А вы пробовали создать своё хранилище?

Comment: Я такой новичок во всём этом, что даже не совсем понимаю, что это за ключи в принципе.

Comment: Я создал свой ответ на площадке, с более развёрнутом варианте о создании, важности, и использовании собственного хранилища ключей - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1435144/Как-установить-хранилище-ключей-keystore-для-публикации-игры-unity-2019-2022/1435145#1435145