# Как установить хранилище ключей (keystore) для публикации игры UNITY 2019-2022

Tags: unity3d, keystore

В этом вопросе я расскажу о создании собственного хранилища ключей для приложения, и его важности

Comment: "В этом вопросе я отвечу на вопрос " немного путает . Лучше бы типа: "В ответе я объясню, как"

Comment: @Сергей, спасибо) действительно не заметил этого

Comment: Спасибо большое. <3

Answer (score 0):

### Что такое хранилище ключей (`keystore`)?

Изначально в `Unity` по умолчанию создаётся `Development Keystore` (хранилище ключей для разработки), с  ним невозможно выпустить приложение в магазины, его `.apk` не подписывается уникальным ключем, и грубо говоря не имеет авторство/владельца, но его можно запускать на прямую через установщик apk в любое физ. устройство где есть такой установщик. Такое хранилище нужно чтобы при сборки приложения оно подписывалось одним из ключей хранилища (ключей может быть больше 1-го), и закреплялось за этим хранилищем уже в магазине, и уже после первой публикации в любом из магазинов, обновлять данное приложение в магазине можно только с этим подписанным хранилищем, смена хранилища на другое блокирует обновление приложения. Хранилище нужно хранить в безопасном и надёжном месте, его кража или потеря будет равна потере доступа к уже опубликованному приложению

**!!! Восстановить хранилище ключей нельзя !!!**

### Как создать хранилище ключей?

Открыть `File => Build Settings => Player Settings => Publish Settings => Keystore Manager`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажать `Keystore => Create New => Anywhere`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее указать путь и название ключа, я использую название с компании/студии под которую веду работу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее заполняются данные сверху-вниз:

1. **Password** - пароль для всего хранилища
2. **Confirm Password** - повторение пароля хранилища
3. **Alias** - наименование нового ключа для хранилища
4. **Password** - пароль для нового ключа хранилища
5. **Confirm Password** - повторение пароля нового ключа хранилища
6. **Validity** - Срок жизни для нового ключа хранилища (По умолчанию - 50 лет, можно изменять на необходимое для вашего случая)
7. **First and Last Name** - Имя и Фамилия владельца нового ключа (Обычно это сотрудник компании) **[НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО]**
8. **Organizational Unit** - Должность владельца нового ключа **[НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО]**
9. **Organization** - Компания/Организация в которую входит данный владелец нового ключа  **[НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО]**
10. **City or Location** - Город, где расположен владелец нового ключа  **[НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО]**
11. **State or Province** - Обычно тут я указываю страну, но прямое значение это штат или провинция **[НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО]**
12. **Country Code** - Код страны в два символа (US, KZ, RU, UA) **[НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО]**

После всего этого можно добавлять ключ (Add Key)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее выйдет вопрос хотим ли мы использовать создать этот ключ и использовать его в данном проекте, жмём да
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь он сам выбрал созданные нами ключи, и вписал пароли (пароли нужно будет вписывать при каждом открытии `Unity`, без них при сборке проекта будут ошибка)

При повторном нажатие на `Keystore Manager`, мы можем добавить в это же хранилище ключей еще  ключи с информацией о уже имеющихся там ключей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Как использовать уже созданное хранилище ключей?

Следует нажамать на галочку `Custom Keystore` и нажав на кнопку `Select` выбрать путь до вашего хранилища, ввести пароль для всего хранилища, далее выбрать ключ из доступных ключей и ввести пароль от него, если всё было введено правильно, то при сборке проекта ошибок не будет, и сборка готова к публикации.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]